# Connect SSIS To Snowflake via ODBC

Tags: ssis, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

Our organization is making the migration from SQL Server to Snowflake, and we are now charged with identifying whether or not we should continue with SSIS for our automated processes OR if we should move to Azure Data Factory (ADF).  ADF might make the most sense due to both ADF and Snowflake existing in the cloud, but we have to at least check if we can stay with SSIS as all of our processes would need a re-write if we move to ADF.

Anyhow, I'm attempting to connect to Snowflake using the 32 bit ODBC driver.  I actually downloaded both the 32 and 64 bit versions from the Snowflake site, but when I used the 64 bit ODBC tool to create a System DSN, the DSN I created didn't show up in SSIS.  The 32 bit one did, so that's the one that I'm using.  So I went about and created the 32 bit DSN, and I at first used the externalbrowser authenticator, which actually allowed for a test connection to succeed.  The issue is that we cannot use that authenticator as it fires a browser window to authenticate, and then a dialog box pops up indicating that the connection was successful.  Using this pretty much forces someone to sit and watch the automated processes, and we cannot have that.

Inside SSIS, I created a connection (through Connection Manager), but instead of using a DSN, I instead created string.  The string looks as such:

`Driver={SnowflakeDSIIDriver};server=[server].east-us-2.azure.snowflakecomputing.com;uid=[user];database=[database];schema=[schema];warehouse=[warehouse];role=[prod role];authenticator=snowflake_jwt;priv_key_file=[unc location]\rsa_key.p8`

As an aside, I do in fact have the actual values for the server, database, etc., in the string; I simply eliminated them here for privacy reasons.  Anyhow, when I attempt to connect using this string, I get the following error message:

`Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider.  ERROR [HY000] [Snowflake][Snowflake] (44) Error finalize setting:  Marshaling private key failed.`

I checked all of the settings, and everything appears to be in order.  I can actually use these same settings in DBeaver, private key file and all, and get a connection.  So it's odd to me that I cannot get a connection in SSIS (although yes, Microsoft is known for wanting everything used to be theirs).  But if I can get a connection in DBeaver, why can't I get a connection in SSIS?

I've done a bit of Google searching, and what I've found is that the error most often appears when there is an issue with the password or credentials supplied.  I've verified the credentials, and, as stated above, using the same ones I can get a connection in DBeaver.  So does anyone know why I cannot get one in SSIS?

Comment: I know nothing of snowflake a bit about SSIS - what the package/project protection level of your test package? The path to the priv_key_file is a UNC - is it actually a UNC or a mapped drive to a network path? When you run the package, are you running in 32 or 64 bit mode? Are you running as you or have you deployed to a server and are scheduling via SQL Agent (or some other scheduler)?

Comment: The protection level of both the package and the dtsx file is DontSaveSensitive.  And the user (me) has access to the network path that is being accessed, and I am using the full UNC path, not the drive letter.

In addition to this, I'm running in 32 bit mode as I mentioned in the original question.  And no, I'm not running on a scheduler; this is being run manually in VS.

Comment: Try changing the project and package protection level to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, open the connection manager and if it's able to connect and retain the connection, then we can infer it's something to do with the DontSaveSensitive setting wiping the sensitive information. I have a solutions for that. As for asking which mode you're running in, you did specify that you created both the 32 and 64 bit DSN on the machine but only the 32 bit was visible and you've specified you're not using the DSN and using a DNS-less approach. *But*, unless you changed the project properties settings, it's 64

Comment: Snowflake doc (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/odbc/odbc-windows) suggests: 64bit system dsn, also authenticator is only needed for federated auth so maybe doesn't make sense having snowflake_jwt in your connection? neither the token?

Comment: So I changed the protection level to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey, and that didn't change the outcome.  I also tried EncryptAllWithUserKey, and that didn't do anything either (that is, I still get the Marshaling error).  I also checked the debug options, and I have Run64BitRuntime set to FALSE, which means it should run using 32 bit.  I'm stumped at this point.

One thing I have noticed is that when I test the connection and it fails with the marshaling error:  the connection goes from being online to being offline.  That is, I have to right-click and uncheck Work Offline.